# ¿Cómo puedo habilitar el botón FullfilmentRequest? en Shopify

Tags: shopify

Estoy en el proceso de revisar mi solicitud de dropshipping. Estoy esperando solo un paso que se me requiere y es habilitar un botón fullfilmentRequest. La siguiente imagen muestra lo que me envía el revisor de Shopify.

Intenté seguir la documentación: https://shopify.dev/docs/api/admin-rest/2023-10/resources/fulfillmentrequest
pero no me funciona, me da error 422, este fragmento de código se está ejecutando en el webhook de creación de órdenes

```
// payload is a body of webhook
        const fullfilmentOrder = await shopify.api.rest.FulfillmentOrder.all({
            session: session,
            order_id: payload.id,
        });
        const fulfillment_request = new shopify.api.rest.FulfillmentRequest({session: session});
        fulfillment_request.fulfillment_order_id = fullfilmentOrder.data[0].id;
        fulfillment_request.message = "Fulfill this ASAP please.";
        await fulfillment_request.save({
            update: true,
        });
```

Para ese código específico recibo este mensaje de error

```js
HttpResponseError: Received an error response (422 Unprocessable Entity) from Shopify: 
[
   "The fulfillment order's assigned fulfillment service must be of api type"
 ]
 If you report this error, please include this id: 28fef8d3-0a5e-4f75-8ad7-cdabfc716f66
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Hola, podrías pasar tu pregunta a español para que se pueda entender mejor.

Comment: @Richi listo ya deje la pregunta en español

Comment: Alguna sugerencia?